# Conformal Coating on LEDs

Tags: led

I have SMD LEDs in my design and are used for light indication where light intensity is critical.

In such scenario, is it good to add conformal coating on the LEDs, does it impact the output (light)?

Is there any solvent, coating material which will less impact?

Comment: Most conformal coatings are UV reflective so yes, they impact light but how much is not always clear from the datasheets.

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: so its better to avoid coating on LEDs

Comment: Just place the equivalent of drinking straw(s) over the LED(s), conformal coat, then remove the straws.

Answer (score 2):

I thought of an LED that might work for your application. It features a ceramic package that makes it more environmentally robust and also conducts heat away from the LED chip more effectively than the usual clear epoxies they use.  You may be able to use a conformal coating with these, because of the ceramic package.  And because you said your application is indication, the optical properties of an additional, relatively thin coating, should not cause a problem.

The following is a table of ceramic package series from Cree that I think would work:

[image: Table of Cree LED Series XLamp XH-B, XH-G, MHB-B, MHD-G]

And here is a [Digi-Key search](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/optoelectronics/led-lighting-white/124?FV=-1%7C90%2C7%7C1%2C7%7C2%2C-8%7C124%2C-5%7C39275%2C-5%7C39276%2C-5%7C46459%2C-5%7C55107%2C-5%7C69114%2C1989%7C0&quantity=10&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&k=LED&pageSize=50&pkeyword=LED) that might help.

If you have a directional application, or an application where it's tough to remove the heat, it's probably better not to conformally coat your LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

Even clear coating will have a different refractive index than air. So, that means that the lens and reflector design of your LEDs won't work.

So, no, this is not an option.

Also, most higher-power LED designs depend at least partially on convective cooling, and coating would *drastically* reduce the ability of the PCB and the LEDs to lose heat. I hope you're factoring that into your design.